# $broadcast vs.$stateProvider in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, state, broadcast

I am passing the response from about 5 $http  .get and .post methods from controllers to other controllers. I was planning on using broadcast to deliver those responses. However, it seems state.go might be the better route. (no pun intended :) . I already have a few states defined,  should I simply add other non url switching states for passing those parameters?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you should use **Resolves in Angular Routes**

```
//Example 
$routeProvider
    .when("/chat", {
        templateUrl: "msgView.html",
        controller: "msgController",
        resolve: {
            messages: function($http){
                //return your $http.get calls data
        }
    }
});

//use resolve like this in controller
app.controller("msgController", function (messages) {
    $scope.messages = messages;
});
```

You could also make this state an abstract or do the resolve work in your top most parent state or in the immediate parent state.

Example using ui-router

```
$stateProvider
  .state('chat', {
    url: '/chat',
    templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
    controller: 'msgController as vm',
    resolve: {
      messages: function($http){
                //return your $http.get calls data
        }
    }
  });
```

By doing this you will ensure that your data is available before you init your view and controller. If your data is empty or partial then you can handle that according to the way you want in your controller like show "No data available" message or something.

This also ensures that if any error occurs in your resolve then the user will be redirected to the 404 page or any other page you specify in

```
$state.defaultErrorHandler((error: any) => {
                $state.transitionTo("404");
            });
```

Comment: sounds good. several of the routes already defined use the res.data which is received from those get and posts. That's why resolve is a good idea right? so that we don't start a new view if data is missing? what if i only have partial data received and some is missing, but i still wish to instantiate the new state?

Comment: i noticed you use ngRoute as opposed to ui-Router

Comment: @uniXVanXcel I have updated my answer and included ui-router and Yes to this " so that we don't start a new view if data is missing?" question.

Comment: one last thing, what if i do not want to change URL, but just pass an error message on the page i am currently on

Comment: then you can do something like this $state.defaultErrorHandler((error: any) => {
                console.log("Error");// Or some other ui notification or anything you want
            });

Comment: dont mean to be a pest, but how do you actually use that defaultErrorHandler? i find very little documentation about it...

Comment: No problem, you could use defaultErrorHandler in .run method of the module. or you could also use this $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ 
        // this is required if you want to prevent the $UrlRouter reverting the URL to the previous valid location
        event.preventDefault();
        ... 
}).